# Access to a base class field during construction

Tags: java, class

I have the following class:

```
public class Base{

    private String str;

    public Base(String str){
       this.str = str;
    }

    public String getStr(){
        return str;
    }    
}

public class Derived extends Base{

    public Derived(){

        super("String");
        System.out.prinln(getStr()); //Is it reliable?

    }

}
```

Is it reliable to get acces to a a base class intance during the construction of a derived class?

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: @NamanGala I;m asking the question becuase in C++ it is not good to do such things. Maybe in Java too...

Comment: you just need to take care of NullPointerException, which in your case will not occure.

Comment: Perfectly reliable... because in making a derived class object you are initializing the super class field... hence it will work everytime...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `str` member was initialized when calling `super("String")` so it is safe to use it immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

super() is used to invoke parent class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid in java. If you wish to be super-duper-completely safe, you can add a `super.` operator like such:

```
public Derived(){

        super("String");
        System.out.println(super.getStr()); //Is it reliable? Yes!

}
```

This way you are sure it's the super's `getStr()` method and not some other class/library's.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe in the given example, but I will not be comfortable with it. What happens if someone subclasses `Derived` and overrides `getStr` as follows:

```
package src;

public class Derived2 extends Derived {

    public Derived2() {
    }

    @Override public String getStr() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived2();
    }
}
```

Making `getStr` final might be a good option.